# How to use an image as a div background?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I have several psd images I created that I want to use as a background for different divs on a website. (These are saved as .pngs and .jpgs respectively) An example look that I'm trying to go for is http://www.brioitalian.com/index.html.

I'm using the bootstrap framework. Every time I try to attempt this my div remains a box with the image inside of it, rather than the actual image representing the div. For example, the Brio website center content div has torn-paper like edges.

I feel like this should be quite simple but it is driving me nuts.

Comment: This is a pretty general question. It helps to have a jsfiddle or something up so someone can go in and see what you've tried already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not related to bootstrap.  Rather, it is setting the background for an element.  I use the following as my standard CSS for adding background images to `<div>`, `<span>` or `<a>` html tags.

```
.background{
    background-image: url(background.image.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  /* image will appear only once*/
    height: 100px;  /* height of image */
    width: 100px;   /* width of image */
}
```

However, this is basic way of implementing this.  There is a good tutorial at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp that show the different options that can be done with background images.